# Vertical align a DIV along another DIV

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm using Bootstrap and have re-created my problem here:

https://jsfiddle.net/nxkzxd2b/1/

I have tried:

```
.square1 {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.square1 {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.square2 {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square1">
    <p>
      Div vertical center
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="square2">
    <p>
      Text normal
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to vertical align the red box along the blue box. I don't have a fixed height for the container. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What exactly does _"I want to vertical align the red box along the blue box"_ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your div's vertical aligned in the middle, you need to apply `vertical-align: middle;` to both of your elements.

**CSS**

```
.square1, .square2 {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

```css
.square1 {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.square2 {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square1">
    <p>
      Div vertical center
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="square2">
    <p>
      Text normal
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxkzxd2b/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
.container {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.square1,
.square2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class (something like `valign-wrapper`) and add it to your `.container`

```
.valign-wrapper{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
}
```